# Strange symbols in Outlook 2010

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010

What can these symbols in an emailmessage depend on in Outlook 2010:

```
�text text text t�st, text text sts� t
```

Answer (score 0):

This could be a formatting issue... To fix, I think you should try setting to Unicode UTF-8.

> Click the orange "File" tab in the top left corner of the Outlook 2010
>   window and click "Options" on the pull-down menu. A new window titled
>   "Outlook Options" appears.
>
> Click the "Advanced" heading on the left side of the window and then
>   scroll to the "International Options" heading near the bottom.
>
> Place a check in the box labeled "Automatically select encoding for
>   outgoing messages" and click "Unicode (UTF-8)" on the drop-down menu.
>
> Place a check in the box labeled "Automatically select encoding for
>   outgoing vCards" and click "Unicode (UTF-8)" on the drop-down menu.
>
> Place a check in the box labeled "Allow UTF-8 support for the mailto:
>   protocol."

[Source](http://smallbusiness.chron.com/setting-outlook-use-utf8-32242.html)